# Change font from Times new roman to Courier New

Tags: r, ms-word, rtf

I am trying to change font from time new roman to Courier new when it gets exported to word document, but unable to figure it as default font is times new roman

```
 rtf <- RTF("New.rtf",   width=7,height=7.27,font.size=9,omi=rep(1,1,1,1))

  addHeader.RTF(rtf, title = "Names", subtitle= "Class", font.size=9, top = T)

  addHeader.RTF(rtf, title = "Subset: Roll no", subtitle= "Actual Number: XXXXXXXXXX", font.size=9, top = T)

  addTable.RTF(rtf,as.data.frame(iris),font.size=9,row.names=FALSE,NA.string="-", col.justify='L',header.col.justify='L', col.widths=rep(c(0.9,0.9,0.9, 1, 1.5)))

  startParagraph.RTF(rtf)

  addText.RTF(rtf,"Data is pasted from IRIS data.")

  endParagraph.RTF(rtf)

  done.RTF(rtf)
```